# I need to write a SQL Server query. to get same name column values of a table in a single row

Tags: sql-server-2012

My SQL Server table has three columns:

```
Customer     Name               SOW
---------------------------------------
100068       Teradyne           59140
100068       Teradyne           63396
100068       Teradyne           38999
100057       CISCO              58056
```

Output should be like this:

```
Customer     Name          SOW
----------------------------------------------------
100068       Teradyne      59140, 63396, 38999, 60
100057       CISCO         58056
```

All the `SOW` column values belonging to same `name` value should be in a single row as shown above.

I need to write a SQL query to achieve the above output.

Below is the query I have written for the same,

```
SELECT 
   SS.[Name],
   STUFF((SELECT '; ' + US.[SOW] 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [SOW]
FROM 
    TBL_MSA_SOW SS
```

Comment: OK, great - and can you show us what **YOU** have tried so far?? Where are you stuck? What are your current results??

Comment: hi Marc, tried using stuff function, but was unable to get the required output

Comment: sure Marc will do that.

Comment: YOu're missing a `FROM` inside the `STUFF` - what table are you selecting those rows from ?? You're using an `US` alias on the `US.[SOW]` column - but there's never a **table** in a `FROM` clause that has this alias .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "inner" select is incomplete - you're using an `US` table alias in the `SELECT` column list - but there's never a `FROM` clause that has a table with that alias....

Also, you're not "linking" the outer `SELECT` list with the inner query.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   SS.[Name],
   STUFF((SELECT '; ' + US.[SOW] 
          FROM TBL_MSA_SOW US
          WHERE US.Customer = SS.Customer
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [SOW]
FROM 
    TBL_MSA_SOW SS
```